# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clint'

Tags: python

Problem is:
[sudo] password for kali:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bruter19.py", line 2, in 
from clint.textui import colored
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clint'

Comment: I tried "pip install clint" but it don't work

Comment: You're probably running Python via an IDE or something that's using a different environment/virtual environment than the one you're installing to. Without knowing what you're running your scripts via, though, we can't do more than just give vague suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have package clint installed. You can install it in command line via pip:

```
pip install clint
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python script needs the module named `clint` for execution. So you can install it by first executing `pip install clint` in the Terminal and execute the Python script.

Thank You :)